# Problems installing on terminal, I keep receiving a "E: sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)"

Tags: package-management, dpkg, g++, qt5

I have recently installed Ubuntu. Initially all was fine and installations worked as instructed in various threads.

I have now encountered a problem while trying to download an editor for Python, specifically while trying to build and install qt5. When I try and install g++ using `sudo apt-get install build-essential` I received the following errors:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... 50%
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
build-essential is already the newest version (12.1ubuntu2).
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 13 not to upgrade.
8 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/119 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] dpkg: error processing package apport (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
No apport report written because the error message indicates it's a follow-up error from a previous failure.
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of apport-gtk:
 apport-gtk depends on apport (>= 0.41); however:
  Package apport is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package apport-gtk (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up python-cairo (1.8.8-2) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python-cairo.postinst: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python-cairo.postinst: pycompile: not found

dpkg: error processing package python-cairo (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
Setting up python-gobject-2 (2.28.6-12ubuntu1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python-gobject-2.postinst: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python-gobject-2.postinst: pycompile: not found

dpkg: error processing package python-gobject-2 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached

dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-gtk2:
 python-gtk2 depends on python-cairo (>= 1.0.2-1.1); however:
  Package python-cairo is not configured yet.
 python-gtk2 depends on python-gobject-2 (>= 2.21.3); however:
  Package python-gobject-2 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python-gtk2 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached

dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-glade2:
 python-glade2 depends on python-gtk2 (= 2.24.0-4ubuntu1); however:
  Package python-gtk2 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python-glade2 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-vte:
 python-vte depends on python-gtk2; however:
  Package python-gtk2 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python-vte (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached

dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of pypar2:
 pypar2 depends on python-gtk2 (>= 2.8.6-1); however:
  Package python-gtk2 is not configured yet.
 pypar2 depends on python-glade2 (>= 2.8.6-1); however:
  Package python-glade2 is not configured yet.
 pypar2 depends on python-vte (>= 0.12.2-1); however:
  Package python-vte is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package pypar2 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu3) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 apport
 apport-gtk
 python-cairo
 python-gobject-2
 python-gtk2
 python-glade2
 python-vte
 pypar2
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Could someone please help?

Answer (score 1):

The resolve is sometimes not that easy, especially if `apport` itself is involved, here is the way I would approach it:

First as mentioned bring your `apt` list up to speed with:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Now onto fixing the problem itself:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall apport
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

And if this is still not enough downloading the packages in question from [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com) and installing them with:

```
sudo dpkg -i <package-name>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, again the 'sudo apt-get update' works fine, giving 4 hits. However the '--reinstall apport' command returns an error 'Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/apport_2.20.1-0ubuntu2.1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)' . I then proceeded to download the package from the website but during the installation the error: 'Errors were encountered while processing:
 apport_2.20.1-0ubuntu2_all.deb' was met. I tried doing it with the apport-gtk package but similarly, an error was met concerning the package.

Comment: Dis you try to run the `sudo apt-get -f install` ?

Comment: Yes, it gave me an 
'Errors were encountered while processing:
 apport
 apport-gtk
 python-cairo
 python-gobject-2
 python-gtk2
 python-glade2
 python-vte
 pypar2
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)' 
error

Comment: O.k, try a `sudo dpkg --configure -a`

Comment: Returns: 'Errors were encountered while processing:
 python-gobject-2
 python-cairo
 apport
 python-gtk2
 pypar2
 apport-gtk
 python-glade2
 python-vte'

Comment: Ould it be easier to just delete or remove a bunch of programs/ packages and start again from scratch ?

Comment: You mean backup your data and files and start over by fresh installing Ubuntu? This would definitively fix it for sure, but its a very inconvenient answer.

Comment: That is what I meant. The thing is all my data is already backed up because of the recent hard drive partitioning and I have very little data on my Ubuntu partition. As I have no knowledge in what is wrong and need to rely on people from this form then it might be easiest.

Comment: It for sure will save you a lot of headache, just make sure you do an `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` when you have fresh installed, even when you click download updates while installing it is not necessarily on the newest.

Comment: What do those two commands do ?

Comment: The first updates the cached lists of software, the second does an update to installed packages, you should definitively aim to keep em up to date.

Comment: Thanks I'll keep that in mind. Again a big thank you for trying to help !

Answer (score 0):

You are holding packages in inconsistent state.
Please run `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt-get -f install` to resolve dependencies problems.

Comment: The first command ran fine and gave me 17 upgradable packages. However the second command gave a similar error, ie with the same errors while processing.

Comment: Sorry, I can't actually post the error in detail...